# Mobile Web APP href link to phone settings

Tags: javascript, html, mobile

Does anyone knows if there is a way to add a link to the phone menu settings from a mobile web app html page? Just like native apps (Android, iPhone), when the app requires the location to be enabled, most app have a link that goes directly to the phone settings screen, thanks.

My question is related exclusively to a mobile web app. To clarify, when I said MOBILE WEB APP, I am basically saying an HTML WEBSITE running from a mobile web browser such as Chrome, Firefox, Opera, etc... This question is not related to native apps. I have read about deep linking and perhaps there is a way to use deep linking to link to the actual phone and not just to apps.

Comment: If you're running Ionic: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/open-native-settings/

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Obsidian Age. Actually I already saw the "Opening the Settings from another app" article but my question is related to a mobile web app and not a native app and that article talks about iOS, etc.. So definitely it is not a duplicate question. Neither I use ionic. A simple HTML5 website running on a mobile phone (also called mobile web app). Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer no a html 5 page can not fire the device to open it's settings. That would cause a security concern. As you could open a webpage and that page could simple take control of your device and pop the settings dialog on your device - not pretty!

If your trying to get geo location data there are some other ways of doings this.

1. use a free third party api such as http://ip-api.com/docs/api:json
2. use HTML5 geo location https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp
3. use a native wrapper such as https://phonegap.com/ use a bridge to native code.

Comment: Thanks MartinWebb, that's the answer I was looking for. I was not sure it was possible, now I know it is not, thanks a lot. Not related to location, I just mentioned as a sample but thanks again.